# How to solve this equation with SciPy (Both sides include f(x))

Tags: python, scipy

[image]

How can I solve this equation with Scipy? Both sides include "y".

For example, range of x = 1 to 10.

Edit: I tried "scipy.optimize.root" function for above equation and it works but it doesn't work for belove equation:

```py
from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np
v_arr = np.linspace(0,2,100)
J_sc = 0.0006
J_0 = 4.07
KT_q = 0.026 
Rs = 5
Rsh = 1000
def function(I_L, v_arr):
    return ( J_sc - J_0*exp((v_arr + I_L*Rs)/KT_q) - (v_arr + I_L*Rs)/Rsh - I_L)
result = root(function, np.zeros(len(v_arr)), v_arr )
print ("answer {}".format(result.x))
```

and output is just zero: `answer [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. .... 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`

Answer (score 1):

Does it work for you?

```py
from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np

def function(y, x):
    return 1-2*np.exp((2*x+3*y)/5.0) - (1+2*y)/3.0 - y 


_xArr = np.arange(1,10)
result = root(function, np.zeros(len(_xArr)), _xArr )

print ("answer {}".format(result.x))
```