# SciPy, solve equation with "root" method

Tags: python, scipy

If i try to solve like this equation with scipy.optimize.root method, it's okay, scipy can do this:

(both sides include f(x) or y)

[image]

But if i try to solve this equation, it only generates "0" root:

(Both sides include "f(x) or I ")

[image]

```py
from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np
v_arr = np.linspace(0,2,100)
I_L = 0.0006
I_0 = 4.07
KT_q = 0.026 
n = 1
Rs = 5
Rsh = 1000

def function(I_out, v_arr):
    return ( I_L - I_0*exp((v_arr + I_out*Rs)/KT_q) - (v_arr + I_out*Rs)/Rsh - I_out)

result = root(function, np.zeros(len(v_arr)), v_arr )
print ("output:{}".format(result.x))
```

and output is just zero: `output: [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. .... 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]`

Comment: Just a comment, if you would communicate with people who tries to help you, it will be much better for everyone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65774384/how-to-solve-this-equation-with-scipy-both-sides-include-fx/65777983#65777983

Comment: i am grateful to you, stephan , but i am new at stackoverflow and I could't manage to enter the comment that I wanted. Also my question has been closed for lack of details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at [root](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html), and the [OptimizeResult](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult.html#scipy.optimize.OptimizeResult) object which it returns.

In the code below the optimisation is arranged in each point of v_arr separately 
and as initial guess (x0) for new point of optimisation (from v_arr[index]) we take
the answer for the previous optimised point (which was obtained for v_arr[index-1]). Also if optimisation in any point of the algorithm
does not converge we print an error message and stop the process.

```py
from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np

v_arr = np.linspace(0,2,100)
I_L = 0.0006
I_0 = 4.07
KT_q = 0.026 
n = 1
Rs = 5
Rsh = 1000

def function(I_out, v_arr):
    return ( I_L - I_0*np.exp((v_arr + I_out*Rs)/KT_q) - (v_arr + I_out*Rs)/Rsh - I_out)


result = np.zeros(len(v_arr))
x0 = -0.5

for index, value in enumerate(v_arr):
    pointResult = root(function, x0, value)
    if pointResult.success == True:
        result[index] = x0 = pointResult.x[0]
    else:
        print("Try to improve your method.\nLast point optimisation result:\n")
        print(pointResult)
        break
print(result)
```